# How to display data from two arrays in one table in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I am using Vue.js combined with Java and JDBC to create a web application. My schema is structured like so:

```
CREATE TABLE Person(
    person_ID serial not null unique,
    email text not null unique,
    password text not null,
    first_name text not null,
    last_name text not null,
    phone text,
    mobile text,
    industry text,
    bio text,
    active boolean default true,
    city text,
    find_out text,
    role text not null,
    notes text,
    profile_photo bytea,
    
    PRIMARY KEY (person_ID)
    
);


CREATE TABLE Mentor (
    mentor_ID serial unique,
    email text not null unique,
    career_history text not null,
    preferred_communication text not null,
    mentoring_preference text not null,
    linked_in text,
    capacity int not null,
    feedback_rating int,
    feeback_comment text,

    PRIMARY KEY (mentor_ID),
    CONSTRAINT fk_person FOREIGN KEY (email) REFERENCES Person(email)
);
```

On one page, I want to display the details of a Mentor, and their given details from Person as well, for e.g I want to show First_name from person as well as career_history from Mentor on table.

The code for my vue controller is

```
"use strict";
var registerMentorApi = '//localhost:8072/api/register/mentor';
var mentorApi ='/api/mentors';
var personApi = '/api/user'
const app = Vue.createApp({

    data() {
        return {
            // models (comma separated key/value pairs)
            mentor: new Object(),
            mentors: new Array(),
            persons: new Array(),
            signInMessage: "Please sign in to continue."
        };
    },
    
    mounted(){
        this.getMentors();
        
    },

    methods: {
        // comma separated function declarations
        registerMentor() {
            // send POST request to service to create mentee
            axios.post(registerMentorApi, this.mentor)
                    .then(() => {
                        window.location = 'registermentor.html';
                    })
                    .catch(error => {
                        console.error(error);
                        alert("An error occurred - check the console for details.");
                    });
        },
        
        getMentors(){
            axios.get(mentorApi)
                    .then(response =>{
                        this.mentors = response.data;
            })
                    .catch(error =>{
                        console.error(error);
                        alert("An error occured - check the console for details");
            });
            
            axios.get(personApi)
                    .then(response =>{
                        this.persons = response.data;
            })
                    .catch(error =>{
                        console.error(error);
                        alert("An error occured - check the console for details");
            });
        }


    }

});

// other component imports go here

// import data store
import { dataStore } from './data-store.js'
        app.use(dataStore);

// mount the page - this needs to be the last line in the file
app.mount("main");
```

and my HTML code for the table is

```
 <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>First Name</th>
                        <th>Last Name </th>
                        <th>Phone Number</th>
                        <th>Email </th>
                       
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr v-for="mentor in mentors">
                        
                    <tr v-for="person in persons">
                        <td>{{mentor.mentorID}}</td>
                        <td>{{person.firstName}}</td>
                        <td>{{person.lastName}}</td>
                        <td>{{person.phone}}</td>
                        <td>{{person.email}}</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

This currently shows only all of the data from Person, and none from mentor, how can I make it so it will show the data from both person and mentor for a given person on the same line?

Note: The arrays for persons and mentors will contain mentor and person objects each with the values specified in the schema

Comment: I think you should share some input arrays as an example. We could figure out what inputs you have. If you do a minimal reproducible example, you'll get more chances to get helped! - https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: You can create a `computed` value which returns an array with the combined rows you want rendered.

Comment: @PeterKrebs how exactly do I do that? Sorry I'm new to Vue

Comment: You search *vue computed* on the internet and find the documentation. Examples are provided there. Especially if you're new to Vue - read the docs! Combining two arrays can also be looked up on StackOverflow or other places on the internet.